# Consulta sobre variables de sesion en php

Tags: php, login, session, registro

tengo la siguiente pregunta:

Con el siguiente codigo de `php` puedo mostrar el `login` de mi sitio si el usuario no ha iniciado sesion, pero si ha inciado, puede ver el contenido.

```
if(isset($_SESSION["login"] && $_SESSION["login"] == "ok")){

  /*=================================================
  HEADER
  =================================================*/

  include "modules/header.php";

  /*=================================================
  MAIN CONTENT
  =================================================*/
  if(isset($_GET["route"])){

    if($_GET["route"] == "home" ||
    $_GET["route"] == "my-glossaries" ||
    $_GET["route"] == "all-glossaries" ){

      include "modules/".$_GET["route"].".php";

    } else {

      include "modules/404.php";

    }


  }



  /*=================================================
  FOOTER
  =================================================*/
  include "modules/footer.php";
}
else{
  include "modules/login.php";
}
```

> La duda es la siguiente: Como no he iniciado sesion, solo puedo ver la pagina del login. Ahora, si doy click en "REGISTRARME", en el login, deberia llevarme a `modules/register.php`
>
> Pero al dar click en el boton, cambia la ruta a "register" pero me sigue mostrando el formulario para iniciar sesion.

**¿Como puedo hacer para permitir abrir la pagina login, y de ahi poder ir y volver a la zona de registro?**

Probe hacer

```
else{
   include "modules/login.php";
   include "modules/register.php";
   }
```

Pero de todas maneras solo muestra el login, y si doy click en registrarme, como ya dije, cambia la ruta pero no se renderiza nada.
Espero haber sido claro, muchas gracias.

> EDIT: Perdon, sí se renderiza la pagina de registro, pero esta a continuacion de la pagina de login. Yo quisiera que sean dos paginas separadas y poder ir de una a la otra.

Comment: No debes crear rutas con el contenido de la superglobal $_GET, expones tu sistema de directorios.
Para mostrar el contenido luego de login hay muchas opciones. Entre otras 1. usar un switch para determinar que se muestra y servirlo desde ahí como bloque html o 2. usar la función header() para cambiar el encabezado y redirigir a  la página pertinente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es normal que te salgan las 2 páginas consecutivas, así es como lo estás haciendo al poner los 2 includes.
La cosa es, que deberías verificar la URL actual, [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php) se dice cómo hacerlo.
Y si resulta que la página es "register.php", no hacer nada más.
Esto lo podrías hacer así:

```
if(isset($_SESSION["login"] && $_SESSION["login"] == "ok")){

  /*=================================================
  HEADER
  =================================================*/

  include "modules/header.php";

  /*=================================================
  MAIN CONTENT
  =================================================*/
  if(isset($_GET["route"])){

    if($_GET["route"] == "home" ||
    $_GET["route"] == "my-glossaries" ||
    $_GET["route"] == "all-glossaries" ){

      include "modules/".$_GET["route"].".php";

    } else {

      include "modules/404.php";

    }


  }



  /*=================================================
  FOOTER
  =================================================*/
  include "modules/footer.php";
}
else{
  if ([NO ES register.php]){
    include "modules/login.php";
  }
}
```

Creo que algo así, podría ayudarte... Seguramente se podrá hacer de muchas maneras y mejores formas, pero para no trastocar mucho lo que ya tengas hecho... Creo que es lo más rápido de programar.

Un saludo!